# Prevent modification of an entity mapped to a parent entity in JPA

Tags: hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa, mapping

I have an entity A that is mapped to another entity B. I want to allow our developers to find A and see the details of B via mapping (`a.getB()`) but prevent them from updating B in any way.

I know this is an odd scenario but there are entities we have that we want to completely separate from other entities to force them being loaded via different services. These entities do need to be available for complicated criteria queries we use to grab search results.

We have scenarios where we need to do this regardless of the type of relationship between A and B (one to one, one to many, many to one).

We have B's ID as a field on A and that's how we manage/update the relationship between the two entities.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like a use case for [@Immutable](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.2/javadocs/org/hibernate/annotations/Immutable.html) annotation.
You can either mark the A.b attribute as immutable, or place the annotation on B entity. It’s up to you to decide which way makes more sense in the context of your app.

Also, check out an article [How to map an immutable entity with JPA and Hibernate](https://vladmihalcea.com/immutable-entity-jpa-hibernate/)